# Spring Boot - Async method not executing

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE
Java 1.8.0_201

I have been writing Spring Boot applications for a little while now and have just run into an unexpected problem. As far as asynchronous execution is concerned, generally I'm using `@Scheduled` methods, but in this instance am using `@Async`. Methods annotated with `@Scheduled` have been working fine, but the `@Async` annotated method introduces some interesting issues.

When I launch the application, I get the following in the console log:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'missionPlanner' could not be injected as a '<my package>.MissionPlanner' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:
    <my package>.IStatsLogger


Action:

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.
```

This is the first unexpected problem. After a little research and taking the error suggestion, I added the following to the `@EnableAsync` annotation in the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true, mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan("<my package>")
public class ServiceConfigurer {
  ...
}
```

This fixed the error and allows the application to start and run. *I don't understand why this needed to be done.*

Unfortunately the `@Async` annotated method does not run. I put in obvious logging output but nothing shows up in the log.

I'm sure that I've used `@Async` methods before that worked, and am truly confused as to why it doesn't work here.

By the way, this class also has a `@Scheduled` annotated method and it **does** execute, just like clockwork.

Here's a snippet of the service:

```
@Service
public class MissionPlanner implements IStatsLogger {
  ...
  @Async
  public void dummy() {
    logger.info("Here's DUMMY!");
  }
  ...
  @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${service.statsReportPeriod}")
  @Override
  public void logStats() throws ServiceException {
    ObjectSwapper<?> swappedObj = ObjectSwapper.swap(statsSwapper,
        new ObjectSwapper<Object>(context.getBean("serviceStats")));
    StatsWriter.write((ServiceStats) swappedObj.getObject(), statsSerializer);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try after adding `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` to your application.properties?

Comment: How do you call `dummy`?

Comment: @aksappy That did not work.

Comment: @hotzst I don't. If you have a class annotated with Service and a method annotated with Async, shouldn't it be called "automatically"?

Comment: No. The `Async` annotation means that the method call is executed in a different thread, then the method from which it is called, if it is called from a spring bean.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I had made the wrong assumption. Thanks for that information. Please post that as the answer so I can accept it.